# Error in plotting ggplot in nested dataset with multiple variables to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested

I was doing a data analysis on prostate cancer dataset.

I wanted to see the predictions and residuals based on status of patient and cause of death.

So I first nested the dataset, made models, mapped the model to the nested dataset and created predictions and residuals.

I want to visualize the predictions and residuals using `ggplot2` and unfortunately, I got the error.

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type `grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame`. Defaulting to continuous. Error:

> Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (502): y

I can see that in `y`, there are 502 elements. I have no idea how to visualise this massive dataset. The dataset is attached as a screenshot (sorry, do not know how to upload a file).

[image: dataset]

```
#load libraries
install.packages("broom")
install.packages("purrr")
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(modelr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(rlang)

#preparing data-nesting
#grouping my categorical variable
#interested in death cause and status

by_deathcause<-prostate_data_clean %>% 
  group_by(cause_of_death, status_) %>%
  nest() 

##building models
model1<-function(df){
  lm(serum_hemoglobin~sdate, df)
}    

#nesting and modelling
by_deathcause<-by_deathcause %>% 
  mutate(mdls=map(data,model1)) %>% 
  mutate(resids= map2(data, mdls, add_residuals), 
         pred=map2(data, mdls, add_predictions))

#unnest prediction
pred<-unnest(by_deathcause, pred)
resids<-unnest(by_deathcause, resids)

#plot the prediction
pred %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sdate, pred, group=status_))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth()

#want clearer view on each cause of death!
pred %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sdate, pred, group=status_))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~status_)

#plot the residual  !!!!!!!!!!!!
resids %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sdate, resids, group=cause_of_death))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE)

#model 2
model2<-function(df){
  lm(diastolic_bp~sdate, df)
}                

#nesting and modelling
by_deathcause_dia<-by_deathcause %>% 
  mutate(mdls=map(data,model2)) %>% 
  mutate(resids= map2(data, mdls, add_residuals), 
         pred=map2(data, mdls, add_predictions))

#unnest prediction
pred2<-unnest(by_deathcause_dia, pred)
resids2<-unnest(by_deathcause_dia, resids)

#plot the prediction
ggplot(data=pred2, mapping=aes(sdate, pred2))+
  geom_line(aes(group=status_))+
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE)

#want clearer view on each cause of death!
ggplot(data=pred2, mapping=aes(sdate, pred2, group=cause_of_death))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~status_)

#plot the residual  !!!!!!!!!!!!
resids2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sdate, resids2, group=cause_of_death))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

Comment: Screenshots are data are rarely helpful. I have two suggestions. 1) Try to consider using Reproducible examples. Not everyone has Your data.... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
2) Go thru your code line by line and weed out the code that is not a problem. This will help others and Yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your process, so I'll just point out where the error comes from and how to deal with it.

Here we have a tibble as a column for another tibble.

```r
suppressWarnings(library(tidyverse))

df <- tibble(x = 1:10)
df$nest <- tibble(y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10))
```

This is the structure of `df` where you can see that `nest` is a column in `df` which itself is a tibble.

```r
str(df)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ x   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>  $ nest:Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ y: num  -0.7 -0.455 0.729 0.572 -0.535 ...
#>   ..$ z: num  -0.6152 -0.6212 -0.804 -0.0456 0.5856 ...
```

Trying to use the `nest` column for plotting gives an error, as it did in your case.

```r
# Doesn't work
ggplot(df, aes(x, nest)) +
  geom_point()
#> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
#> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): y
```

You can deal with this error by subsetting the nested column with `$`. Normally this is ill-adviced to do within `aes()`, but it makes sense with nested columns.

```r
# Access columns in the nested data.frame with `$`
ggplot(df, aes(x, nest$y)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Off-topic; you don't necessarily need to post your entire script, just the bits with some (dummy) data that is able to reproduce your error. You can post a snippit of your data by copying the result of `dput(head(my_data))`, if the head of the data is all what is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your method works fine for the residuals, but for predictions, it works fine without subsetting it. May I know why, though?

Comment: Is is possible that the residuals were stored in a nested tibble/data.frame and the prediction was stored as a regular column? You should never `$`-subset a regular column name inside `aes()` as it leads to weird results.